# KI-67 IHC staining, counting colored cells in an microscopic image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, semantic-segmentation

I am trying to write a python code to count the total of cancerous and normal cells in microscopic images. The tissue is stained with KI-67 IHC staining, which causes the cancerous cells to be brown and the normal cells to be blue. I can't get the code to be specific enough to count every brown cell, and my code is not able to count the blue cells due to brightness problems. Help is much appreciated!

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
from skimage import io

# Load the image and create a copy for further processing
image = cv2.imread("images/NET1.jpg")
original = image.copy()

# Convert the image to the HSV color space for color analysis
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Define the HSV range to target brown colors
hsv_lower = np.array([0, 0, 0])
hsv_upper = np.array([20, 255, 255])

# Create a binary mask based on the specified HSV range
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, hsv_lower, hsv_upper)

# Create a kernel for morphological operations
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3))

# Perform morphological opening and closing operations to refine the mask
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)
close = cv2.morphologyEx(opening, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=2)

# Display the processed mask
io.imshow(close)

# Find contours in the processed binary image
cnts = cv2.findContours(close, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

# Define parameters for cell counting
minimum_area = 10
average_cell_area = 100
connected_cell_area = 100
cells = 0

# Loop through the contours and count cells based on their area
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > minimum_area:
        cv2.drawContours(original, [c], -1, (36, 255, 12), 2)
        if area > connected_cell_area:
            cells += math.ceil(area / average_cell_area)
        else:
            cells += 1

# Print the total number of detected cells
print('Cells: {}'.format(cells))

# Display the processed mask and the original image
cv2.imshow('close', close)
cv2.imshow('original', original)

# Wait for user input to exit
cv2.waitKey()
```

These are the used pictures:

[image: NEC tissue]

[image: NET1 tissue]

The code processes an image to detect and count cells that match a specified brown color. It loads the image, converts it to the HSV color space, and creates a mask to isolate the brown-colored regions. Morphological operations are applied to refine the mask. Detected cells are counted based on their area, and the results are displayed with the original image. The program waits for user input to exit.

Comment: What about some more complex segmentation or insurance detection algorithms? For example starmap.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution, can you maybe give me an example of how to use it? I can't find a way to use it for my problem.

Comment: Why do you convert the image to hsv color space? And are the uploaded images exactly the images you are working on? To me alraedy `cv2.inRange` does not seem to get all the brown cells. Since you know for that counting the unwanted cells are blue, why not work on the blue channel of the original image and threshold it to remove most of the blue cells?

Comment: @Flow, working in the HSV color space makes targeting specific colors easier. The pictures I uploaded indeed are the exact images I am working with. Can you explain how you would target this specific problem. I have no background in writing algorithms so I am a little lost at the moment.

Comment: your pictures are screenshots, not the actual pictures. the second picture looks severely compressed. -- throw some AI at it. semantic segmentation should be able to handle this. then it's just a matter of counting the connected components.